# How to see the last character in a stringstream object with O(1) constant complexity?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to get ride of trailing newlines on a `std::stringstream` object after flushing some stuff into it. For now I would try something like this:

```cpp
const char* inputvalue = "My line\n";
std::stringstream stream;

stream << std::string{inputvalue};
stream.seekp( -1, std::ios_base::end );

if( stream.peek() == '\n' ) {
    stream << " ";
} else {
    stream.seekp( 0, std::ios_base::end );
}
```

Is this the most efficient way to do so i.e., fewer CPU instructions and time?

As a side note, can I completely remove the last newline other than putting a space character to get rid of the new line without sacrificing performance?

Comment: How performance sensitive is this code?

Comment: I am reading a file by lines, and I am casting way the new line characters coming with the line itself. I am using [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize) to get the line. The other problem is that [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize) returns a `const char*`. You can find a minimal code here on [my other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482802) question. See the line `while( ( readline = PyObject_CallObject( fileiterator, NULL ) ) != NULL ) {`

Comment: Could you manipulate the raw `char*` data instead?

Comment: Maybe I can convert the `const char* pointer` to `char * pointer` and set `pointer[size-1] = '\0';`?

Comment: The first problem seems to be the unnecessary `std::string{inputvalue};`. Having said that, `stringstream` is not particularly fast. The `iostream` methods are good for human-readable formatting, and humans just aren't fast. So speed was not really a design goal.

Comment: I am building a big string and when I tried `stringstream << const char*` it raised an exception, then, I added the `std::string{const char*}`. Is there a better wat to build a big string other than using `stringstream`?

Comment: You could dupe the string, yeah, and then work with it.

Comment: std::string has some pretty useful functions for finding last characters which you could then erase. If you had a char array you could use a while loop and remove the characters yourself. Also, don't set the character to a space set it to nul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding the thing on the `stringstream` I am taking the `const char*` and checking whether it has the new line `\n` on it. If so, I am casting it to `char*` and ending the string with `\0` on `size-1`.

```cpp
Py_ssize_t linesize;
std::stringstream stream;

char* nonconstcharline;
const char* constcharline;

for( PyObject* linepy : linecache ) {
    constcharline = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize( linepy, &linesize );

    if( constcharline[linesize-1] == '\n' ) {
        nonconstcharline = const_cast<char *>( constcharline );
        nonconstcharline[linesize-1] = '\0';
        stream << std::string{nonconstcharline};
    }
    else {
        stream << std::string{constcharline};
    }
}
```

I read on this other question [How to use const_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554841/how-to-use-const-cast) I should not do `const char*` to `char*` and change it as I do not seem to own the `const char*` thing, but so far no problems.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at `std::string_view`.